# Is drilling a hole in a wet hollow (cinder? cement?) block wall a terrible idea?

Tags: water-damage, cinderblock

I have a wet basement wall. I am working on hiring someone to regrade and possibly install an external French drain, but in the meantime..

Would it be a terrible idea for me to drill a 1/2" hole at the orange dot in the picture so that I can snake a scope down through the blocks to see what I can see? I'm really curious if there are pools of water inside the blocks.

[image: proposed drill site]

Comment: Won't hurt.  Doubt the water is that high, but might be possible if water does not spread out.  Will only show the few inches of that section/column, not what the rest of the wall looks like.

Comment: Oh, maybe I am not understanding how the wall is constructed. I imagined that I could stick a scope straight down the whole way from that spot - I think it should be in the hollow of each block below it. Are they not built like that?

Comment: If you have a means of dealing with the water inside (sump pump) just drill an 1/8" hole at the bottom, and see what comes out.

Comment: Should be able to stick a scope all the way down, but it will only show that line of hollows.  It won't show the hollows on the sides.  Depending on how well the blocks are sealed to each other, water might only be found in a limited amount of lines of hollows.

Comment: Hard to tell how old this is, but in my neck of the woods, code required every other hollow to be filled with concrete and rebar, so if that code was in effect in your area, you may or may not hit a hollow space.

Comment: Anti-climatic update: as best as I can tell, it's hollow until very near the floor where there is a solid block. There was nothing remarkable inside the blocks, at least where I drilled.

Comment: Write up an answer, include boring/unremarkable pictures ;^)

Comment: To what end? With no answers, if I VTC, it will delete this in a month, and I don't want that, but this isn't particularly useful, so -1.